# Mesh is not affected by Bone rotation, but it's still affected by Weight Painting

Tags: weight-painting

I have a model composed of different parts linked by a single armature, one of them is a face with fully-working weight painting set to various bones, which are all parented by a main bone (the head bone).

[image]

However, when I try rotating the head or the neck (head's parent), the mesh ignores it and stays in place, but it still gets deformed since the bones themselves have moved, as you can see here.

[image]
[image]

It rotates normally if I parent the face to the head bone without weighting, so it's something with the weight maps. 
I already checked: Armature/Bone scaling, Parenting, Origin points, Weight maps.

What's even weirder is that the chest bone (neck's parent) can be rotated normally without causing the glitch, as it was meant to be.
[image]

Any ideas? I really wish there is a way to fix this without redoing the weight painting of the child bones, since I already spent a lot of time working on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the head is only being affected by the head bone and its child bones, probably there is another bone, like the neck or the chest that is moving the head. Go to the list of bones and check everybone and then make the bone head affect all the area that you want to move (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you said at first, but you are right. I selected the face object in Object Mode, went to Object Data Properties and removed every name unrelated to the face in the Vertex Groups, leaving only the head bone and its child bones. Now it's rotating properly, thanks!